# How do I concisely check warning categories up to the root of the hierarchy in my package?

Tags: perl, warnings, hierarchy, pragma

I know how to `use warnings::register` to create custom warning categories for my module.  However, if I create warning category `Module::category` and warn using `warnif()`, `no warnings 'Module'` does not suppress the warnings.  How can I concisely check both `Module::category` and `Module`?

#### MCVE

```
package Provider;
use strict; use warnings;

use warnings::register qw(undefined);

sub foo {
    warnings::warnif('Provider::undefined', "Undefined parameter!");
}

package Consumer;
use strict; use warnings;

Provider::foo;      # warns - OK

{
    no warnings 'Provider::undefined';
    Provider::foo;  # does not warn - OK
}

{
    no warnings 'Provider';
    Provider::foo;  # _DOES_ warn - oops  <===========
}
```

#### Other investigation

If I check the state of the warnings inside `Provider::foo()`, I see that `no warnings 'Provider'` doesn't touch `Provider::undefined`:

```
sub foo {
    print "$_: @{[warnings::enabled($_) ? 'enabled' : 'disabled']}\n"
        foreach qw(Provider::undefined Provider);
 }
```

gives

```
Provider::undefined: enabled
Provider: enabled
Provider::undefined: disabled
Provider: enabled
Provider::undefined: enabled
Provider: disabled
```

for the three tests above.

#### A workaround

```
sub foo {
    my $should_warn = 1;
    foreach (qw(Provider::undefined Provider)) {
        if(!warnings::enabled($_)) {
            $should_warn = 0;
            last;
        }
    }
    warnings::warn('Provider::undefined', "Undefined parameter!")
        if $should_warn;
}
```

... but before I wrap that in a module and put it on CPAN, I'd like to find out if anyone else has already done so, or knows a better way :) .  Google and SO searches were unavailing.

Comment: It's interesting, the core warnings categories are hierarchical but it does not seem registered package subcategories are registered under the package name category. Maybe this could be a feature request.

Comment: @Grinnz I was thinking about that myself - I've not yet used perlbug, so maybe it's time :)

Answer (score 2):

The `use warnings::register qw(undefined);` statement introduced two new categories of warnings, `'Provider'` and `'Provider::undefined'`. So check for both

```
sub foo {
    if (warnings::enabled('Provider') and 
        warnings::enabled('Provider::undefined')) 
    {
        warnings::warn('Undefined parameter');
    }   
}
```

This will not fire if either of categories is suppressed

```
{
    no warnings 'Provider';               # EITHER stops it
    #no warnings 'Provider::undefined';

    Provider::foo;                        # does not warn
}
```

To require both `no warnings` to stop them use `or` in `::enabled` condition in `foo`.

---

To  reduce typing of `Provider` in module's subs you can set up a utility sub for that, for example

```
my $to_warn = sub  {
    return 0 if not warnings::enabled(__PACKAGE__);
    warnings::enabled(__PACKAGE__ . '::' . $_) 
        or return 0  for @_;
    return 1;
};
```

and then can do

```
warnings::warn('Undefined parameter') if $to_warn->('undefined');
```

More defaults can be set up in `$to_warn`. Now the name `Provider` need not be typed at all :)

Recall that `$to_warn` must be defined before it's used, or at least pre-declared.

Comment: Sure - like another workaround I was thinking of, namely `List::MoreUtils::all { $_ } map { warnings::enabled($_) } qw(Provider::undefined Provider)`.  Do you know of a module that does this, and prevents me from having to repeat `Provider`?

Comment: @cxw By `use warnings::register qw(undefined);` two categories of warnings are introduced, `'Provider'` and `'Provider::undefined'` (it does suck typing it over and over!) I think you have to spell out both?  Can write a utilitiy sub in the module itself so to reduce typing in subs, of course.

Comment: @cxw Was backwards, fixed.  Added an example utility sub to reduce typing